# How to implement timeout in python truly?

Tags: python, eventlet

How to truly implement timeout in python? http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/timeout.html

Code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import eventlet
import time
import sys
import random

while True:
        try:
         with eventlet.timeout.Timeout(1, False):
                print 'limited by timeout execution'
                while True:
                        print '\r' + str(random.random()),
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                        eventlet.sleep(0)
                print ' Never printed Secret! '
        except Exception as e:
                print ' Exception: ', e
        finally:
                print ''
                print ' Timeout reached '
                print ''
```

Time out will never reached. Where am I wrong?

P.s. I replaced:

```
 time.sleep(0.1)
```

with:

```
 eventlet.sleep(0)
```

Add False for exception, now it works well:

```
with eventlet.timeout.Timeout(1):
```

change to:

```
with eventlet.timeout.Timeout(1, False):
```

But it works only with eventlet.sleep(0.1)

E.g this code wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import eventlet
import time
start_time = time.time()
data = 0
with eventlet.timeout.Timeout(1, False):
        while True:
                data +=1
print 'Catch data ', data, ' in ', time.time() - start_time
```

I simply add sleep 0 seconds:

```
eventlet.sleep(0)
```

And it works like a charm.

<s>Solved</s>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

eventlet's Timeout isn't as magical as you'd hoped.  It can only detect timeouts in "greenthreaded" code -- code that uses eventlet's system of cooperative multihtreading.  As noted in [the Timeout docs](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/timeout.html), "you cannot time out CPU-only operations with this class".  `time.sleep` pauses with Python's internal threading system, not eventlet's greenthreads.

Instead, use [eventlet.sleep](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/greenthread.html#eventlet.greenthread.sleep) which works correctly with greenthreads.

Comment: @stackterminator Replace "time.sleep" with "eventlet.sleep".

Comment: i'll place stdout to question.

Comment: Is there eventlet try / except? (:

Comment: If you read the Timeout docs, you'll see that it's behaving exactly as expected: Timeout raises itself as an exception if the timeout expires before the block completes.  You'll find an example of how to catch the Timeout in the docs.  As expected, your finally block runs before the exception ends your program.

Comment: Thx alot, i change line: `with eventlet.timeout.Timeout(1):` with this `with eventlet.timeout.Timeout(1, False):` crashing disappear.

Comment: looks like eventlet raise its own exception

Comment: Up! Up! Why doesn't it work without sleep? i place the code at the bottom with additional question.

Comment: Because you do not give eventlet a chance to run. You may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14227272/revisions

Comment: Thanx alot, my hook is eventlet.sleep(0)